# C - Expanding an array of structs with pointers already existing inside it

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, realloc

I have an array of structs that is declared as such

```
typedef struct bucket{
    char * value; 
    char * key; 
}BUCKET;

typedef struct item{
    struct bucket * data;
    struct item * next;
    struct item * prev;
}ITEM;

typedef struct base{
    struct item * first;
}BASE;

typedef BASE *SPACE;
```

It works perfectly for everything that I had to do with it. Basically I have to do an implementation of a hashmap in C. I managed to do it, but I am completely stuck on this one task. I need to make the hashmap resizable by the user.

If I want a hashmap of size 5, I do so:

```
SPACE *hashmap = malloc(sizeof(SPACE *) * 5);
```

and it works perfectly for the purpose of the program.

However, if I try to resize it using the following block of code:

```
void expandHashspace(SPACE *hashmap){
    printf("Please enter how large you want the hashspace to be.\n");
    printf("Enter a number between %d and 100. Enter any other number to exit.\n>",hashSpaceSize);
    int temp = 0;
    scanf("%d",&temp);
    if(temp>100 || temp<hashSpaceSize){
        printf("Exiting...\n");
    }
    else {
        SPACE *nw = NULL;
        nw = realloc(hashmap, sizeof(SPACE *) * temp);
        hashmap = nw;
        hashSpaceSize = temp;
        printf("Your hashspace is now %d rows long.\n", hashSpaceSize);
    }
}
```

It also works properly. However, when I go to utilise the hashmap itself, it ends up with a segmentation fault. Or SIGSEGV Signal 11.

For example, I have the following display function.

```
void displayHashspace(SPACE *hashmap){
    printf("\n");
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hashSpaceSize && hashmap; i++){
        BASE *linkedList = hashmap[i];
        if(linkedList) {
            ITEM *node = linkedList->first;
            printf("\n[HASH %d]\n", i);
            while (node) {
                printf("\t[BUCKET %d]\n\t[VALUE] : %s\n\t[KEY] : %s\n\n",j, node->data->value, node->data->key);
                node = node->next;
                j++;
etc...
```

Using CLion's debugging, I realised this:
Let's say the hashmap size is 3. That would mean that only hashmap[0-2] exist.
If I resize the hashmap to, let's say 10, it allows me to resize.
However, while displaying, the address of hashmap[3] is really weird.
Whereas every other address is pretty long, with almost 8 digits or more, the address of hashmap[3] is always `0x21`.

After this, once it reaches `ITEM *node = linkedList->first;` with linkedList being hashmap[3], the segmentation fault occurs.

Here's another example. Here's my saving function:

```
void saveHash(SPACE *hashmap){
    FILE *f = fopen("hashmap.hsh","w");
    fprintf(f,"%d\n",hashSpaceSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < hashSpaceSize;i++){
        if(hashmap[i]){
            ITEM *save = hashmap[i]->first;
            do{
                fprintf(f,"---\n%s\n%s\n",save->data->value,save->data->key);
                save = save->next;
            }while(save);
etc...
```

Here, the story is different. It can only reach hashmap[0] before crashing after the resizing. Using the debugger, I found that somehow, the save, which is set to hashmap[0]->first (which normally works before expanding), has a BUCKET whose VALUE variable is suddenly set to NULL for some reason, hence the crash.

I tried setting every "new" BASE after expansion to NULL, but the save function still breaks after using `expandHashspace()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SPACE *hashmap = malloc(sizeof(SPACE *) * 5);` is a type error. You have the same type on the left (`SPACE *hashmap`) and the right side (`sizeof (SPACE *)`). The left side should have one star more (as in `int *p = malloc(sizeof (int))`).

Comment: `hashmap` is a local variable in `expandHashspace`. Assigning to it is pointless because by the time the function returns it will be gone.

Comment: damn, I'm dumb. thank you, made the method return the hashmap itself and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reallocating memory to hashmap wasn't working because hashmap was being a local variable in that method. Meaning everything just became a confusing nightmare.

Returning the hashmap itself instead of returning nothing solved every problem.